# linux booting process

Tags: assembly, boot, processor

I started leaning the booting process of Linux OS. It says that the first program executed by the processor is `BIOS`. I want to know what will be the contents of the `instruction pointer` and what is the first instruction that is executed by the microprocessor?

Moreover, are these `BIOS` instructions actually brought into the `main memory` to execute?? If yes, then where are these instructions loaded, i mean the `starting address` . If no, whats the reason in not bringing them into the memory?

Adding to these, where does the `interrupt vector table` actually resides? `RAM` or `ROM`??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note: this is all for x86. This may be different for other platforms.

What the instruction pointer points to first, well, depends. Typically, a processor will set this to 0 on reset, but it's defined by the processor and ultimately, who made it. In the case of x86, it will jump to 0xFFFFFFF0 ([source](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up)). This will just contain a jump to a useful section of BIOS code.

Your BIOS then needs to start setting up your system. To do this, it executes directly from its ROM chip, since your memory hasn't been properly initialised now. This is specific to the platform, but typically on x86, the BIOS will put the CPU into cache-as-RAM mode, allowing it some temporary storage while it sets up the memory.

It will then set up the rest of the system. This includes the IVT, which resides at the bottom of memory (0x0) and other useful stuff ([source 1](http://wiki.osdev.org/Memory_Map_%28x86%29), [source 2](http://duartes.org/gustavo/blog/post/how-computers-boot-up)).

Answer (score 0):

BIOS has nothing to do with the operation system. It depends on the processor architecture and you need to study the specific processor developer guide to find the answer.

For x86 based machines the instructions pointer points to the last memory location in the ROM which contains the starting address of first BIOS instruction. Using the Jump address processor executes the BIOS routine and then hands over the control to the booting device

Comment: So, do you know what is that instruction in the last memory location of the ROM??

Comment: I told you it is a JUMP instruction

Comment: So, what about my last question?? IVT is it on RAM or ROM??

Comment: I am going to ignore your question because, you have not read the site FAQs and you do not care to read the answer carefully